# Why does python generate a string json file?

Tags: python, json

I would like to generate a json file from data retrieved in an api request and another json file. The problem is that in my generated json file, the braces are surrounded by double quotes and I also have "\n" and "\r" everywhere. Do you have a solution to generate a json file correctly?

A piece of my python code:

```
def write_json(data, filename='data.json'):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
        json.dump(data, wf, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

# JSON file to fetch IDs
with open('sast-projects.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    projects = json.load(f)

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    temp = data['data']
    
    for project in projects:
        result_detail = requests.get(url_detail + str(project['id']), headers=header_detail)
        temp.append(result_detail.text)
        write_json(data)
```

And an example of my outpout (data.json):

```
{
    "data": [
        "{\r\n  \"id\": 12,\r\n  \"teamId\": 34,\r\n  \"owner\": \"Some text\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Some text\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}",
        "{\r\n  \"id\": 98,\r\n  \"teamId\": 65,\r\n  \"owner\": \"Some text\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Some text\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `result_detail.text` to `result_detail.json()`. You're trying to store the raw json string instead of a json object, which is causing double encoding issues.

Comment: Thank you! I changed this. And now I've this error "TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable". Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Sounds like there is some value in data that is a method. If it should be what is returned from that method, you may have forgotten the () when calling it to set that value

Comment: Yup, I screwed that up- json is a method and not a property like text is. So turning it to `result_detail.json()` should resolve it. I've updated my answer.